# tcpdump inside a shell script captures nothing

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I want to start a TCP program and capture the related packets,
my shell script `cap.sh` is as below:

```
    sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w mypcap &
    sleep 3
    ./tcp_receiver
    sleep 2
    x=`ps -ef|grep "tcpdump"|grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $2}'`
    sudo kill -9 $x
```

I run `cap.sh`

```
    sudo ./cap.sh
```

so actually in this shell, I can run `sudo` without password
and the host just a virtual slice on a remote machine (PLanetlab node)
although I can see the process `tcpdump` from `ps -ef`
it captures nothing
I see the `mypcap` file is 0 bytes after the `cap.sh` finishes

what are potential reasons?
and how to make the tcpdump in a shell script capture the packets?
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `kill -9`.  Not only is it almost always the wrong thing to do, it might be causing the problem here, by having buffered data be discarded rather than written to disk.  Use plain old kill, or `kill -2`.

Another option is to add in the `-U` option to flush the output buffer after every packet.

Comment: Finding the PID by grepping the process list is also a bad idea. If there is any other instance of tcpdump, you will kill that process as well. Instead, save the PID after you start tcpdump using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1911387/138329 .

Answer (score 0):

One potential reason: eth0 doesn't exist in the virtualised environment.