# How to get right PID of a group of background command and kill it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Ok, just like in this thread, [How to get PID of background process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-pid-of-background-process), I know how to get the PID of background process. However, what I need to do countains more than one operation.

```
{
           sleep 300;

           echo "Still running after 5 min, killing process manualy.";
           COMMAND COMMAND COMMAND

           echo "Shutdown complete"
}&
PID_CHECK_STOP=$!
some stuff...
kill -9 $PID_CHECK_STOP
```

But it doesn't work. It seems i get either a bad PID or I just can't kill it. I tried to run ps | grep sleep and the pid it gives is always right next to the one i get in PID_CHECK_STOP. Is there a way to make it work? Can i wrap those commands an other way so i can kill them all when i need to?

Thx guys!

Comment: Try `()` instead of `{}`

Comment: already tried not working same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kill -9` kills the process before it can do *anything* else, including signalling its children to exit. Use a gentler signal (`kill` by itself, which sends a TERM, should be sufficient). You do need to have the process signal its children to exit (if any) explicitly, though, via a `trap` command.

I'm assuming `sleep` is a placeholder for the real command. `sleep` is tricky, however, as it ignores any signals until it returns (i.e., it is non-interruptible). To make your example work, put `sleep` itself in the background and immediately `wait` on it. When you kill the "outer" background process, it will interrupt the `wait` call, which will allow `sleep` to be killed as well.

```
{
       trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
       sleep 300 & wait

       echo "Still running after 5 min, killing process manualy.";
       COMMAND COMMAND COMMAND

       echo "Shutdown complete"
}&
PID_CHECK_STOP=$!
some stuff...
kill $PID_CHECK_STOP
```

UPDATE: `COMMAND COMMAND COMMAND` includes a command that runs via `sudo`. To kill that process, `kill` must also be run via `sudo`. Keep in mind that doing so will run the external `kill` program, not the shell built-in (there is little difference between the two; the built-in exists to allow you to kill a process when your process quota has been reached).

Comment: I still get that error actualy  deploy.sh: line 164: kill: (1498) - Operation not permitted Would that be a security right problem?

Comment: Can you post something closer to your actual code? This sounds like you are trying to kill a process owned by another user.

Comment: @Franko Please edit the code in your question, not my answer :) However, the fact that you are running a process with `sudo` means you will have to run `kill` with `sudo` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can have another script containing those commands and kill that script. If you are dynamically generating code for the block, just write out a script, execute it and kill when you are done.

Comment: Seems legit I'll do it for now. I'd like to get it in one single script tough.

Answer (score 0):

The `{ ... }` surrounding the statements starts a new shell, and you get *its* PID afterwards. `sleep` and other commands within the block get separate PIDs.

To illustrate, look for your process in `ps afux | less` - the parent shell process (above the `sleep`) has the PID you were just given.