# ECONNREFUSED connect when running Selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I am trying see the actual html content before being rendered by the browser. So I am using selenium-webdriver in node.js.

Here's my code and the error I'm getting:

#### Code

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'); 
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub').
withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
build();
driver.get('http://www.example.com/example/abc');
driver.getPageSource().then(function(html) {
  console.log(html);
  return true;
});
driver.quit();
```

Error

```
/home/abhishek/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1761
      throw error;
            ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/abhishek/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:145:16)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/home/abhishek/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:149:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/home/abhishek/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:123:30)
    at Builder.build (/home/abhishek/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:294:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/abhishek/crawler_postman/crawler_selenium.js:15:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for anyone whose issue was not solved by the only answer, I solved this by including `await` before `driver.actions()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means webserver is not running. Try running `webdriver-manager start --standalone` in a new command line window or tab

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21124867/577977