# Tell if Stop-Process was successful or not in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, start-process

Currently I start processes in PowerShell like this:

```
$proc = Start-Process notepad -Passthru
$proc | Export-Clixml -Path (Join-Path $ENV:temp 'processhandle.xml')
```

to later on kill it like this:

```
$proc = Import-Clixml -Path (Join-Path $ENV:temp 'processhandle.xml')
$proc | Stop-Process
```

The problem is that if the process died before I got to call `$proc | Stop-Process`, I will get error in the PowerShell output. I need to disable this error and just get the Boolean value indicating if Stop-Process was successfully into a PowerShell script's variable. How can I get this info in PS?

Comment: `$?` variable is true if the last executed command was successful and false if it failed. To disable error output set -ErrorAction to SilentlyContinue

Comment: You could also check whether the process exists, before you're trying to kill it.

Comment: @Cole9350, your solution works like charm. You could post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as one. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also use `$proc.HasExited`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `$?` variable to determine the success or failure of your last executed command. Set `$ErrorActionPreference` variable to decide how error output is handled per script, or use `-ErrorAction` parameter to set it per command:

```
$proc = Import-Clixml -Path (Join-Path $ENV:temp 'processhandle.xml')
$proc | Stop-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($?) {
    #Success
    Write-host $proc " Stopped Successfully"
}
else {
    #Failure
    #Use $error variable to retrieve the message
    Write-Error $error[0]
}
```