# Set condiguration to run Cucumber with WebStorm

Tags: cucumber, protractor, webstorm

I am trying to execute my first protractor + cucumber project.

I don't know how to set the Run/Debug Configurations. Here my settings.
What is wrong?

```
Node interpreter
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

Working Directory
D:\example-protractor-master

Javascript file
node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber.js

Application parameters
--specs=features/*.feature protractor-cucumber.config.js
```

When I right click on my feature and select "Run 'matter.feature'" I get this message:

> "Error running matter.feature Can not run program
>   "D:\example-protractor-master"

config screen:

http://screencast.com/t/xCpvbYWjZl

protractor-cucumber.config.js

http://screencast.com/t/lXr7jnNcYT9

Comment: Please post code as code, rather than screenshots of code, and especially instead of *links* to screenshots of code.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used protractor cli as 'Javascript file':

```
Program: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
Working Directory: D:\example-protractor-master
Javascript file: node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js
Application parameters: --specs=features/*.feature protractor.cucumber.conf.js
```

Similar configuration works fine for me

Comment: that really helped! 

But now I'm getting 

Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED

d:\example-protractor-master\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:145
      callback(new Error(message));
               ^

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055593/unable-to-run-protractor-econnrefused-connect-econnrefused, https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner/issues/99 for some hints