# How to increase docker-machine memory Mac

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine, singlestore

I am new to Docker, and trying to go through this tutorial setting up MemSQL from a Docker image - http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/setup/docker/ .  I am on a Mac, and the tutorial uses `boot2docker` which seems to have been deprecated.

The VM needs 4GB memory to run.  The tutorial specifies how to do this with `boot2docker` but I cannot find a way to do this with the docker-machine/docker toolbox.

Here is the command I am using and the error I am getting just trying to go through the tutorial without altering the boot2docker config.

```
docker run --rm --net=host memsql/quickstart check-system
Error: MemSQL requires at least 4 GB of memory to run.
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

when you create docker machine, you can nominate the memory size:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 4096 default
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This definitely seems like the right place to adjust memory allocation.  However, still getting the same error after restarting this VM.   In the `check-system` program (https://github.com/memsql/memsql-docker-quickstart/blob/master/check-system), I am seeing these lines which would determine this error. `ONE_MB = 1024 ** 2`, `virtual_memory = psutil.virtual_memory()`, `if virtual_memory.total < ONE_MB * 3700:
        sys.stderr.write("Error: MemSQL requires at least 4 GB of memory to run.\n")` .

Comment: Wasn't able to get this working by altering the config, but deleting and recreating the docker machine vm as shown above solved the issue!

Comment: Sure, I clean the second way, seems it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 201):

You can do this via the command line. For example, to change the machine from the default 1cpu/2048MB RAM run:

```
docker-machine stop
VBoxManage modifyvm default --cpus 2
VBoxManage modifyvm default --memory 4096
docker-machine start
```

You can then check your settings:

```
VBoxManage showvminfo default | grep Memory
VBoxManage showvminfo default | grep CPU
```

And for `docker-machine inspect` to report the correct state of things, edit `~/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json` to reflect your changes.

Comment: This worked even when the GUI (version 5.0.16) would not.

Comment: This answer should be at the top

Comment: Note that after the command is executed `docker-machine inspect` won't show any changes. However, if you run `docker stats` you'll see that the changes have been applied.

Comment: @slovit and others: You can then modify the docker-machine `config.json` file to reflect the actual size. Example: for `default`, as used in the example solution, modify the `~/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json` file so that the `Memory` (and `CPU` if also modified) subproperty under `Driver` is changed to `4096`. Then, `docker-machine inspect` will show the proper value.

Answer (score 95):

For Docker version 1.12.1 (build: 12133) and higher on macOS there is an option to change CPU's and RAM from UI and restart docker. You can find the preferences from toolbar. Attaching images for clarity.

**Update Aug 2020**: Preferences -> Resources (thank you to @swedge218)

**Old Step** (probably defunct now): Preferences -> Advanced -> adjust resources -> Apply & Restart

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/znltd1v4r00nfpu/Screenshot%202017-03-24%2012.12.58.png?dl=0]

[image: docker advanced tab (memory)]

Comment: This has moved to Advanced tab. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: Man that was both obvious and completely unintuitive - thank you!

Comment: Does those changes also apply if I use dinghy with virtualbox ? Or I should only use VBoxManage to adjust mem size ?

Comment: Is there a command line equivalent to this? I have Docker for mac but apparently docker-machine ls gives me nothing so I can't modify the default machine.

Comment: It's Preferences -> Resources as of today.

Answer (score 45):

Docker Machine maintainer here.  I don't think adjusting the `config.json` manually will work.

Your two options are to either create the machine with `--virtualbox-memory` set, or to adjust the VM's memory in the VirtualBox GUI ("Settings > System" for that VM I think).  Make sure the machine is powered off and there should be a little slider that works.

EDIT: Another answer shows that you can do the in-place operation from the command line as well using `VBoxManage`.

Comment: This works but note that `docker-machine inspect` will continue to report the original amount of memory even after altering it in the VirtualBox GUI.

Comment: That's true, in order to have `docker-machine inspect` report the accurate amount, you _do_ have to edit `config.json` (that's where `inspect` gets its information).

Comment: Doing it in Virtualbox is the simplest

Answer (score 14):

I couldn't get the other answers to work. The only thing that worked for me was to remove the default machine and re-create it with more memory.

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory=4096 --virtualbox-cpu-count=2 --virtualbox-disk-size=50000 default
```

This fix was found here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Using_Docker_Machine_On_Windows?lang=en

Answer (score 14):

Other answers showed how to change the memory using VBoxManage:

```
docker-machine stop default
VBoxManage modifyvm default --memory 4096
docker-machine start default
```

To confirm the change from the command line:

```
VBoxManage showvminfo default | grep Memory
```

OR

```
docker-machine ssh default free
```

Comment: Hi cpep, can you [edit] your answer and [format the code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) properly?

Answer (score 4):

fox xhyve (another virtualization under macos) you can modify ~/.docker/machine/default/config.json
property Driver/Memory (default to 1024)
then restart docker machine to apply changes

Comment: I found it under `~/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json`. Thanks 

Answer (score 3):

**APPLE SILICON**

I was looking for a solution for Apple Silicon, and from what I understand `docker-machine` was deprecated ([link](https://docs.docker.com/machine/)), so I ended up using colima ([link](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima)).

As [per colima documentation](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima#customizing-the-vm) one can define number of cpus and available ram like:

```
colima start --cpu 1 --memory 2 --disk 10
```

and to modify an existing VM:

```
colima stop
colima start --cpu 4 --memory 8
```