# How can my docker harddrive be bigger than the hosts?

Tags: docker

I run some docker images on an EC2 host and recently noticed, that the docker FS is always 100GB. The host FS is only 8GB though.

What would happen, if i use more than 8GB on the docker image? Magic?

Comment: Well, to add that, I already found out how to check the available host disk space. You need to mount a folder on the host system with e.g. `VOLUME ["/var/cache/nginx"]` in your Dockerfile, then you get the free space of the host with `df -h`, when you're inside the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comes from [PR 14709](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14709) and the docker `daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=` option:

> Current default basesize is 10G. Change it to 100G. Reason being that for
>   some people 10G is turning out to be too small and we don't have capabilities
>   to grow it dyamically.
>
> **This is just overcommitting and no real space is allocated till container
>   actually writes data.** And this is no different then fs based graphdrivers
>   where virtual size of a container root is unlimited.

So when you go over 8 GB, you should get a "`No more space left on device`" error message. No magic.

Comment: ok, ty for the clarification. thats what i thought. but can i see from within the docker container, how much space is left on the host drive? I guess its a common problem, how do ppl make sure they can really allocate the space they need?

Comment: @cari the space allocated is minimal, but I am not sure how to check it from a container (that would be a good *new* and *separate* question of its own). That looks like http://stackoverflow.com/q/34430084/6309 and https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18869.