# Change Docker memory from the command line

Tags: ubuntu, docker

First of all, I'm not trying to change the memory allocated to a single container on Docker, I want to change the memory of the Docker app that's running on the computer. I can do this on my Mac from Preferences->Advanced->Memory. However I want to do this remotely via ssh on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

I'm fairly new to Docker, and as far as I've seen, there are ways to change the memory for a single container using the `-m` or `--memory` flag, but I believe they won't achieve what I'm trying to do. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase docker-machine memory Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834082/how-to-increase-docker-machine-memory-mac)

Comment: I am looking for the same answer for Docker on Windows. Is there any cli tool for this?

Answer (score -2):

For Docker for Windows i know it is done over the Hyper-V (VM) settings and i think it is done the same way for the Docker for Mac hypervisor.

I don't think this is posible with a docker setting. There is no option for this mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/).

You could try to set the [--cgroup-parent](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#default-cgroup-parent) and then limit the memory for this cgroup.

Comment: I am looking for the same answer for Docker on Windows. Is there any cli tool for this?