# JRE out of memory in Docker

Tags: java, docker, docker-machine

A am trying to build and sbt 0.13.13 docker image similar to [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/jimschubert/sbt-scala/~/dockerfile/) one. Running `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar sbt-launch.jar` (as a step of building the image) fails with:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000d3026000, 451256320, 0) failed; error='Out of memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 451256320 bytes for committing 
reserved memory.
```

Increasing `-Xmx` doesn' help. What can I do to fix this? This is the Dockerfile: https://github.com/kolov/k8s-stuff/blob/master/scala/Dockerfile

Comment: what are the JAVA_OPS? It looks like you're trying to allocate 430MB of memory

Comment: -Xms512M -Xmx2048M

Comment: @AssenKolov please can you add the output of `docker info` that will give you the total memory available to docker while building the image, incase if the memory is lower that what you are expecting while building your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot,@vedarth. Your suggestion helped to pinpoint the real problem and finding the solution from there was easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834082/how-to-increase-docker-machine-memory-mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase docker-machine memory Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834082/how-to-increase-docker-machine-memory-mac)

Answer (score 4):

Increase the swap space of the hardisk using the following commands

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/myswap bs=1M count=2048

sudo mkswap /var/myswap

sudo swapon /var/myswap
```