# How to change docker memory and CPU settings in mac, without the GUI

Tags: docker

I have docker installed for Mac.  The default max memory and max CPU is set very low (2 cores and 2 GB).  I am aware that I can easily change this through the GUI, by clicking the docker whale Icon, Then going to 'Preferences', 'Advanced', and moving the CPUs and/or Memory slider.

However, I need to change this in bash without making use of the docker GUI.  I was looking around but having a hard time finding out how to do this.  I read about something called virtual box.  Is there a way to do it without virtual box, or any other external programs (just by using docker)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase docker-machine memory Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834082/how-to-increase-docker-machine-memory-mac)

Comment: unfortunately I don't have control over creating the docker machine so can't specify at that time.  And so was hoping to set this setting in docker (equivalent to what setting it in the UI would do) prior to others creating docker containers.