# How can I limit the recources available to Docker Engine in the command line?

Tags: docker

I.e., one can change it in Docker's settings [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHnr0.png) (i.e., using GUI). Can I limit the memory using the command line instead using OSX?

The problem is that after I set its memory limit to 10GB I cannot start Docker anymore and it just hangs.

*Update*:
I did read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834082/how-to-increase-docker-machine-memory-mac), but I believe it doesn't apply to me since I don't have a virtual box.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834082/how-to-increase-docker-machine-memory-mac

Comment: see https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Comment: @Ammar I use OSX so the accepted answer doesn't really work for me unfortunately (`docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 4096 default`)

Comment: @LinSel I did read it, but I could find a way to set a memory limit for a docker engine (not for a container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker for mac use `hyperkit vm` just like `hyperv` on windows10, the settings could be in some place like next:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json
```

The default value is:

```
{
  "dockerAppLaunchPath" : "/Applications/Docker.app",
  "proxyHttpMode" : "system",
  "buildNumber" : "31259",
  "cpus" : 2,
  "diskSizeMiB" : 61035,
  "version" : "2.0.0.3",
  "settingsVersion" : 1,
  "channelID" : "stable",
  "memoryMiB" : 2048,
  "displayedWelcomeMessage" : true,
  "displayedWelcomeWhale" : true,
  "linuxDaemonConfigCreationDate" : "2019-06-26 02:32:30 +0000",
  "diskPath" : "Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/Docker.qcow2"
}
```

So, you can use command to modify the value you want to change, next is an example to change memory to 3072M, or just use any editor to directly modify the value:

```
sed -i 's/"memoryMiB".*/"memoryMiB" : 3072,/g' /Users/`id -un`/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json
```

Finally, in command restart the docker as next:

```
osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"' && open -a Docker
```