# How to setup codecept e2e testing with angular2?

Tags: angular, codeceptjs

Im new to e2e testing. i'd like to give it a try with http://codecept.io/angular/

Since i started my app with https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter Protractor/Jasmine is already working.

From what i've understand, codecept is working on top of protractor.
i've installed it correctly but when i launch a simple test i have a failed error.

here's my codecept.json :

```
{
  "tests": "src/app/*_test.js",
  "timeout": 10000,
  "output": "./output",
  "helpers": {
    "Protractor": {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
      "driver": "hosted",
      "browser": "chrome",
      "rootElement": "body"
    }
  },
  "include": {
    "I": "./steps_file.js"
  },
  "bootstrap": false,
  "mocha": {},
  "name": "front"
}
```

And here is my test :

```
Feature('MyApp');

Scenario('First Test', (I) => {
  I.amOnPage('/#/home');
});
```

This is the error log:

```
MyApp --
 First Test
 • I am on page "/#/home"
 ✖ FAILED in undefinedms

 ✖ "after each" hook: finialize codeceptjs in 0ms

-- FAILURES:

  1) MyApp: First Test:
     Uncaught Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

As answered here [Unable to run Protractor - ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055593/unable-to-run-protractor-econnrefused-connect-econnrefused):

```
webdriver-manager update

webdriver-manager start --standalone
```

and this is my codecept.json :

```
{
  "tests": "src/app/*_test.js",
  "timeout": 10000,
  "output": "./output",
  "helpers": {
    "Protractor": {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
      "driver": "hosted",
      "browser": "chrome",
      "rootElement": "body",
      "useAllAngular2AppRoots": true
    }
  },
  "include": {
    "I": "./steps_file.js"
  },
  "bootstrap": false,
  "mocha": {},
  "name": "front"
}
```

Note the "useAllAngular2AppRoots": true

Comment: Have you been succesfully able to use CodeCept, Why do i need too Start Webdriver Manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Protractor in direct mode - this skips the webdriver/selenium server and connects the Protractor helper directly to the browser.

You need to configure Protractor using 'direct' mode like so:
The 'directConnect' value gets passed on to Protractor itself, so it also uses direct mode.

```
"helpers": {
  "Protractor": {
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "driver": "direct", 
    "directConnect": true, 
    "browser": "chrome",
    "rootElement": "body",
    "useAllAngular2AppRoots": true
  }  
},
```