# Exiting first process in pipe when second exists

Tags: shell, pipe, exit

On `sh` or `bash`, how do I exit the first process in a pipe when the second one has exited?

I was using the following to get input from the network:

```
$ nc -l 1234 | myprog
```

`myprog` exited due to an internal cause but `nc` continues to live. Is it possible to stop `nc` also?

Comment: Perhaps you could use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-pid-of-background-process

Comment: How do I do that with piping (preferably in one line)?

Comment: See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html for some options.

Comment: Thanks but I have no idea how to use those notes to solve my problem. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you can fork process with **&** control operator and get the pid of child reading **$!**. So, the simplest solution could be

```
$ ( nc -l 1234 & echo $! > /tmp/myprog_kill_pid ) | myprog; kill $(</tmp/myprog_kill_pid); rm /tmp/myprog_kill_pid
```

Of course, this is not very nice and not suitable for multiple running instances... but you can start from this.

Comment: I did a workaround to my specific problem but thanks for telling how to fork using &.