# how to kill a single background process in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, background-process

I want to kill a single background process in bash

```
$SCRIPT_DIR/utils/monitor.sh -f $root/save &
$SCRIPT_DIR/utils/run.sh -f $save
$SCRIPT_DIR/utils/Monkey.sh  -f $save
```

I want to kill monitor.sh after finishing Monkey.sh.

I tried using pid but its not working.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say 'using pid' is 'not working'.  Do you mean you found the pid and tried to do a `kill <pid>`, or do you mean you couldn't find the pid, or some other possibility?  Also, are you trying to do this programmatically or interactively?

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide i tried pkill monitor.sh as well as  killall monitor.sh but the script runs in the background. i cannot stop it.

Comment: Try adding '-9' as in `killall -9 monitor.sh`.  Is this Linux or Mac?

Comment: linux....gnome 14.04

Comment: if you do `ps aux | fgrep monitor.sh` does it show you as owner?

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide yes... it shows me as an owner
parth    29992  0.0  0.0  13568   760 pts/7    S+   14:37   0:00 fgrep --color=auto monitor.sh

Comment: That's the fgrep process, sorry it's confusing.  Do you see another process in there that has monitor.sh?  That's the one you need to check.  Make sure monitor.sh is running before checking it.

Comment: no this is the only thing i can see...nothing else...and yes the monitor.sh script was running before running this command.

Comment: try looking here - http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/21446-ps-command-does-not-display-shell-script-running.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem might be related to how monitor.sh is called.  If I have a script 'foo.sh' that just has a shell command in it, I won't see it identified as 'foo.sh' in a `ps` listing, but if I call it with `sh` (or `bash`) then I do.  It seems that if 'foo.sh' is a list of shell commands, the shell will change that to bash , and you won't see 'foo.sh' in the `ps` listing, but if I explicitly call it with bash, i.e.

```
bash foo.sh
```

then I see it in the ps listing.

However, best practice for shell scripts, is to start off with the appropriate 'hashbang' command, i.e. for a bash script the first line should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

this also seems to fix the problem for me.  I'm guessing that this line may be missing from monitor.sh, and that's why you don't see it using `ps` or `killall`.  Once that's in place, you should be able to do

```
killall -9 monitor.sh
```

or similar and it will work.  Either that or invoke it as `bash monitor.sh`, but common best practice is to include that first line either way.

cf - http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/21446-ps-command-does-not-display-shell-script-running.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a multiple options:

First, you can use [**kill**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill). But you need the pid of your process, which you can get by using [**ps**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps), [**pidof**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) or [**pgrep**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep).

```
ps -A  // to get the pid, can be combined with grep
-or-
pidof <name>
-or-
pgrep <name>

kill <pid>
```

It is possible to kill a process by just knowing the name. Use [**pkill**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) or [**killall**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall).

```
pkill <name>
-or-
killall <name>
```

All commands send a signal to the process. If the process hung up, it might be neccessary to send a [**sigkill**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL) to the process (this is signal number 9, so the following examples do the same):

```
pkill -9 <name>
pkill -SIGKILL <name>
```

You can use this option with `kill` and `killall`, too.

Read this article about [controlling processes](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x5368.htm) to get more informations about processes in general.

Credit goes to tanascius

You should try

```
killall Monkey.sh
```

Comment: no it doesnot work...i tried killall monitor.sh...pkill monitor.sh but no luck ...the background process is continously running only

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for the 'jobs' and 'kill' command

```
$ ls -l
    total 4.0K
    -rwxr-xr-x. 1 probinson probinso 52 Aug 13 14:25 x.sh
    lrwxrwxrwx. 1 probinson probinso  4 Aug 13 14:28 y.sh -> x.sh
    lrwxrwxrwx. 1 probinson probinso  4 Aug 13 14:28 z.sh -> y.sh

$ cat x.sh 
    for i in $(find / 2> /dev/null ); do echo ${i} &> /dev/null; done

$ ./x.sh & ./y.sh & ./z.sh &
$ jobs
    [1]   Running                 ./x.sh &
    [2]-  Running                 ./y.sh &
    [3]+  Running                 ./z.sh &
$ kill %2
$ jobs
    [1]   Running                 ./x.sh &
    [2]-  Terminated              ./y.sh &
    [3]+  Running                 ./z.sh &
$ jobs
    [1]-  Running                 ./x.sh &
    [3]+  Running                 ./z.sh &

# this should kill job one after job three finishes
$ ./x.sh; x.sh & y.sh & z.sh; kill %1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to save the PID of the backgrounded process:

```
$SCRIPT_DIR/utils/monitor.sh -f $root/save &
MONITOR_PID=$!
...
kill $MONITOR_PID
```

The advantage of this over `killall` is that it will kill this specific process. If you have more than one copy of the script running, this won't kill the other `monitor.sh` scripts that are running concurrently.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911387/1563512

Comment: Agreed, killall is.. overkill here, +1