# How to get PIDs for the list of commands I execute from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Lets say there are 3 `java` commands in my shell script:

```
java com.test.test1 &
java com.test.test2 &
java com.test.test3
```

I need to get the PID of each and every command once it gets executed and store the PIDs in a file.

Note: I cant use `$!` as I'm using `sleep` in between.

Can you help me out?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-pid-of-background-process

Comment: There are many commands that can do the trick, but you can try `pgrep`, which doesn't need a lot of knowledge

Comment: What does using `sleep` have to do with gathering the pid from `$!`? Also, if you're using `sleep` in between, why do I not see it in your example code? Help us help you. Give us the whole picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$!` even if you're sleeping. Simply assign a variable between each invocation:

```
java com.test.test1 & pid1=$!
java com.test.test2 & pid2=$!
java com.test.test3 & pid3=$!
```

If you can't use this please include the whole code. Also, Greg's Wiki has a [great article of how to do this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).