# Using watch with ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, watch

I have the below commands which is running properly on the local machine.

```
watch -t -n1 "echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` | tee -a Time.txt" &>/dev/null &
```

But when I run it from the remote machine I won't create the expected output i.e. Time.txt is not created and will not be running as a background process.

```
ssh ipaddress watch -t -n1 "echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` | tee -a Time.txt" &>/dev/null &
```

Please help me on this. I have tried multiple options like putting ', " for watch command but it did not helped me out.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It is about programming only. I got stuck in the automation scripting. Appreciate if anyone can help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- No need to use `echo` to output the result of a sub shell.
- No need to use `tee` to append to a file.
- No need to use `watch` to sleep for one second.

Try this instead.

```
ssh -t ipaddress 'while sleep 1; do date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S >> Time.txt; done &'
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working i.e. updating the remote machine time after each 1 sec. But how to stop the background process. Is there any way?

Comment: You have to store the [PID of the background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-pid-of-background-process) in order to kill it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ceving. I killed all the sleep process running in the background and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You had incorrect shell syntax: [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh%20ipaddress%20watch%20-t%20-n1%20%22echo%20%60date%20%27%2B%25Y-%25m-%25d%20%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S%27%60%20%7C%20tee%20-a%20Time.txt%22%20%26%3E%2Fdev%2Fnull%20%26)

and throws this error when running the command:

```
Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

You should use the option `-t`

```
-t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a
        remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
        options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

And quote the whole command and pass it to ssh, and escaped characters when neccessary. attached [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh%20-t%20ipaddress%20%27watch%20-t%20-n1%20%22echo%20%60date%20%2B%25Y-%25m-%25d%5C%20%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S%60%20%7C%20tee%20-a%20Time.txt%22%20%5C%26%5C%3E%2Fdev%2Fnull%20%5C%26%27)

```
ssh -t ipaddress 'watch -t -n1 "echo `date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S` | tee -a Time.txt" \&\>/dev/null \&'
```

Comment: It is not working. I am getting the Error opening terminal: unknown, even if i put -t option.