# Open several terminals from shell script and then close them

Tags: shell, sh

I am new to shell scripting and I am not sure how to approach this problem.
I have looked all over Google but I couldn't find a relative answer.

My problem:
I have a shell script that executes two gnome terminals and then do some work.
When the work is done I would like to close both gnome terminals that were opened at the beginning of the shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh

gnome-terminal -x sh -c "./manage.py runserver; bash"
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "yarn start; bash"

... 
Some other work
...

kill gnome-terminal 
kill gnome-terminal 
kill shell script
```

I have tried looking for the child processes id of the shell script and kill them but it did not work.
Any help would be appreciated

Note: it needs to be done only with the default Linux packages since this is part of a project that many people use and I cannot enforce installation of different libraries.

Comment: use `tmux` or `screen` instead of a graphical applications

Comment: I need to follow what is going on both servers while executing the "some other work" part

Comment: `tmux` and `screen`are terminal multiplexers. It allow you to [split a single terminal window](https://www.perl.com/article/an-introduction-to-tmux/) instead of opening a new one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get process ID of background process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-process-id-of-background-process)

Comment: Programmatically opening terminal windows is a bad habit. Have your scripts write their output to a log file, and separately open a new terminal to view that log file if you want to.

Comment: @tripleee I have been given the green light to run the servers in the back without the need of ``gnome terminal``. So I did something like:
``./manage.py runserver  > log1``
``some other comands here``

``yarn start > log2 `` 
However, in this example only log2 is ffilled with logs and in the main terminal I get the execution of first command ``./manage.py runserver``

Comment: Sounds like the first command is logging to standard error; the proper way to redirect is `command >log 2>&1` and of course add `&` to run in the background if desired

Comment: I can see no way for `$!` to be empty if you have successfully started a background process. Even if `foo` is not a valid command, the shell will start a background process and report its PID in `$!` in every scenario I can think of.

Comment: Anyway, your edit to piggyback in a new and basically unrelated question is invalid and I have rolled it back; please ask a separate question if you have two topics.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using Gnome Terminal for this and not some sub-shell or multiplexer as suggested in comments, you can keep the PID of each executed terminal by saving the value of `$!` (last command's PID), and then kill them by PID:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

gnome-terminal -x sh -c "./manage.py runserver; bash" &
TERM1_PID=$!
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "yarn start; bash" &
TERM2_PID=$!

#... 
#Some other work
#...

kill $TERM1_PID 
kill $TERM2_PID
```

Comment: This does not work for some reason. I get an output: 

# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
In addition, on echo-ing the TERM2_PID i see the variables are empty, there is no pid in them

Comment: it does not woik for me in gnome-terminal buster( Just return another PID.

Answer (score 0):

I have been given a green light to drop the usage of gnome terminal and have implemented @tripleee's suggestion:

```sh
python manage.py runserver > ../log 2>&1 & 

some other commands here 

yarn start:3030 > ../log2 2>&1 &
```

It seems to work and the output from each of the 2 commands it directed to log and log2 respectively.

For killing those 2 applications I am using:

```sh
fuser -k <app1 port number>/tcp
fuser -k <app2 port number>/tcp
```